# How to get global data in Python Multiprocess which set in main process?

Tags: python

main.py

```
import multiprocessing.pool as Pool
from test import set_data, get_multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_list = ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
    set_data(data_list)
    res = get_multiprocessing(2)
    print(res)
```

test.py

```
import time
import multiprocessing

_t = None

def set_data(t):
    time.sleep(1)
    global _t
    _t = t

def get_data(idx):

    return _t[idx]

def get_multiprocessing(num_threads):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=num_threads)
    res = pool.map(get_data, range(1))
    pool.close()

    return [r for r in res]
```

and here comes an error

Traceback (most recent call last):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

So is there anyway to get the global data after I set it in main process?

Comment: Each global namespace is global *to one module in one process*. It is never shared. Why don't you pass as an argument?

Comment: Truly global data can only be emulated with multiprocessing, but it won't behave exactly the same - e.g. it cannot hold references across processes and is not cheap to access. What are you trying to solve by using globals? What features do you need?